# Probablity of winning a Jumping game

Tags: binomial-distribution, games

I am playing a game at the moment. I won't mention it but the aim is to make around 150 perfect jumps in a row to get through a level.
You can "practice" It lets you play through the level with errors and it tells you how many attempts you have taken to complete it.
I constructed a binomial to see the probability of finishing a level. But I don't know how correct it is
What approach should it take?

Probability of success

```
=BINOM.DIST(86,144,86/144,TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: If you are succeeding in $\frac{82}{144}\approx 0.6$ of attempts then you extremely unlikely to get $150$ in a row unless you can try to get better first.

Comment: Unless all jumps are about equally difficult a binomial wouldn't suit